# How to find the $\delta$ calculation for a functional limit

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

I want to prove that the function $\cfrac{x+5}{4x-3}$ is continuous at $x = 1$ using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. So I know I need to show that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}{\cfrac{x+5}{4x-3}}=6$$
I'm reading that $\delta$ should be set to $\min(1/8, \epsilon/46)$, but I don't understand how to obtain that.

Based on the definition of continuity at a point, for $x\in \mathbb R\setminus{3/4}$ and any given $\epsilon > 0$, if $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-6|<\epsilon$.

I have that $|f(x)-6| = \cfrac{23|x-1|}{|4x-3|}$ and have tried all sorts of algebraic manipulations to find the bounds of $\delta$, but nothing has worked.

Comment: $|4x-3|\geq 4|x-1|-1$.

Comment: Let $x=1+h.$ Then, $|f(x)-6|=\frac{23|h|}{|1+4h|}.$ If $h>-1/4$ then $|f(x)-6|<\epsilon\iff23|h|<\epsilon(1+4h)\Longleftarrow23|h|<\epsilon(1-4|h|)\iff|h|<\frac\epsilon{23+4\epsilon}.$ Note that $\min(1/8,\epsilon/46)\le\min(1/4,\epsilon/(23+4\epsilon)).$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difficulties with estimation of epsilon-delta limit proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651858/difficulties-with-estimation-of-epsilon-delta-limit-proof)

Comment: @AnneBauval That answer is useful and has helped me with similar problems, but it hasn't helped me with this particular limit.

Comment: Of course but it is extremely similar, so you should easily be able to adapt it. This is why I did not edit my comment above as an official answer. In such situations, moderators blame it and advise to rather vote to close the minor variant as a duplicate.